# How to sort integers and put them on a list

Tags: c++, list, sorting

Basically, I need to read a text file and insert them on `ascending order` in a list.

The text file is,

```
4 1 9 11 0 15 23 2 7 8 17 21.
```

and I need to put them on a list like

0    1    2    4    7    8    9    11    15    17    21    23

The problem says,

- Insert the first item into an empty list. //Which is going to be 4
- For each successive item:

  `If it is smaller than the first item, insert it at position 0.`

  `Otherwise, scan the list from the beginning, looking for the first`

  `item whose value is greater than the current value, and insert`

  `the new item before that one.`

I think I need to sort those by comparison, but I can't come up with clear idea. Can you help me ?

(Because professor is using his own `IList.h` and `IList.cpp` file, all functions I can use is insert and erase.)

=========================================================================

What I tried was,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


ifstream inf(argv[1]);
IList t;
int i1;
int i2;
int i3;
int i4;
int i5;
int i6;
int i7;
int i8;
int i9;
int i10;
int i11;
int i12;

//It is reading each integers from the text file and name it i1, i2, i3..
// The text file is..
// 4 1 9 11 0 15 23 2 7 8 17 21.
// i1 is going to be 4    i1 = 4

inf >> i1 >> i2 >> i3 >> i4 >> i5 >> i6 >> i7 >> i8 >> i9 >> i10 >> i11
>> i12;



//I inserted the first value which is 4
t.insert(i1, 0);

// comparison will start from here..

// when i2 is smaller than i1, we are putting them on the left.

if (( i2 < i1 ))
{
    t.insert(i2, 0);
}

// when i2 is greater than i1, we are putting them on the right.

if (( i2 > i1 ))
{
     t.insert(i2, 1);
}
```

Comment: Using an array (`std::array`, or even a C array) will solve *all* your problems :)

Comment: [Or use a `std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) as the instructions seem to recommend.

Comment: Any specific reason for using a List? You should get all of what you want for free using `std::set<int>`

Comment: I don't think we should be solving homework. Close?

Comment: do you have to write the list by your own?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the following:

```
#include <fstream>    
#include <iostream>    
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    ifstream f(argv[1]);
    istream_iterator<int> b(f);
    istream_iterator<int> e;

    list<int> l;
    copy(b, e, back_inserter(l));

    l.sort();
    for(auto v: l)
        cout << v << endl;
}
```

---

**Explanation**

```
    ifstream f(argv[1]);
    istream_iterator<int> b(f);
    istream_iterator<int> e;

    list<int> l;
    copy(b, e, back_inserter(l));
```

copies the integers from the file into a list using [`istream_iterator`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and the [`copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) algorithm.

Then

```
l.sort()
```

sorts the items using `list`'s method.

Comment: If @sungch hands this in I do believe he may be asked how he came about the answer...

Comment: I think "The problem says" and "Because professor" gives it away:-)

Comment: @graham.reeds :-) Yes, those are good clues. I skimmed the question.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you should to implement is called "Insertion Sort". Check out the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort for more detail.

What it basically does is, it puts the first element into the list and for each following element it walks through the list until it finds the place where it belongs.

What I would do in the first place is creating a list instead of using all these interger fields (this makes your code usable for lists with more or less than just 12 elements).

```
// ...
// read values from file
IList unsorted;
while (!inf.eof()) { // checks if end of file is reached
    unsorted.insert((int)inf.getline());
}
inf.close();
```

Next, create a new list, which holds the sorted list.

```
IList sorted;
sorted.insert(unsorted.get(0), 0); // insert first element
```

Your assignment says to iterate over all elements in the unsorted list. This obviously begs for a for-loop. Your code suggest that you might be unexperienced with that. Please check out control structures. These are absolutely essential. But let me help you out with that.

```
// for each successive item
for (int i = 1; i < unsorted.length(); i++) { // maybe there is another method to check unsorted's length ?!
    int nextValue = unsorted.get(i);
    j = i;

    // as long as the current unsorted element is smaller then the previous element in the sorted list, swap these elements
    while () {
        int temp = sorted.get(j-1);
        sorted.insert(temp, j);
        j--;
        sorted.insert(nextValue);
    }
}
```

I haven't checked if the code compile or produces any runtime errors. But this is more about the concept. Hope this helps!

Best,
Thomas